# Cross Browser Platform Testing

Tags: vuejs2, automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress

My team is currently starting to develop a web application with vue.js. We are currently discussing the test framework and a team member prefers cypress. The only issue is, that cypress is not cross platform testing framework. We have requirements to support Chrome, Safari, Edge, tablet and mobile devices.

Most of the modern frameworks such as vuejs promise cross platform functionality. And the raised discussion that we had in the team is the need of cross platform testing. Is it still so important in 2018(almost 2019) to do cross browser and cross OS Platform tests? What do you use for testing and how do you test your web application?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Of cource the alternative is Selenium using selenium wrappers like Protractor or Webdriver.io or Nightwatch.js.

For same reason, we are not using Cypress. We are using Nightwatch.js. Coz in the above list of wrappers it only has everything inbuilt like cypress. For others in the list we have to find the respective npm for test runner, assertion reporting, parallelisation, etc.

Mainly we have choosed it for internal test runner and junit xml reporting for ci which it gives along with selenium wrapping functionality.

Also one more good thing cypress is working on cross browser support. Recently they have progress in firefox browser.
Refer this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1096) tracker

Comment: I read the  issue of cypress. Also watched yesterday a webinar where they show they wrapper. The main problem is that they don't give a timeline. They presented 4 topics and the last one is the cross platform. For me it sounded like they might release that in an year. Here is the link to the webinar: https://youtu.be/FfqD1ExUGlw?t=2079
I was also thinking about nightwatch.js.

Comment: Yeah I watched it. According to them it is low priority. But as there is more requests comes in.  Lets hope they release in an year :)

Answer (score 0):

We have this same dilemma at my organization. I find Cypress so easy to use that I am ok using it for 99% of my test (that does not include my unit or api test). If I need something special for another browser, which is probably going to be minimal, I would then use a selenium wrapper, for me that would be protractor since we mainly do Angular. I hear a lot of argument not to choose cypress due to the issue that it currently only runs in Chrome, I think sometimes it is an excuse for someone to hate it because they don't want to learn something new. I would bet 90% or more of your test cases Cypress will be just fine, where I need something else I do something else. When I look at the testing triangle, I know most of my test should be UNIT test so I don't have enough UI automation test to worry about it. I will say I have ran into this same argument at my job from developers who say why don't use protractor, and they have the freedom to use protractor, but I notice they never get around to using it. They like to argue about what someone else wants to do, but then they don't even use what they say they prefer. I would ask myself what is going to be the cheapest to implement and be the most effective for me. For me that is mainly cypress and then protractor if I have some special case..

Comment: For me the question is when do you have this special case? How do you catch special cases in all browsers, without testing them automatically? Do you rely on manual tests, until somebody finds out, that something is not working?

Comment: Normally it is something we find odd when a user is using IE. I get what you are saying we might only run in chrome, and if we find something with a manual task we use protractor or telerik